# UIViewContainment Child Controllers Not Sizing Correctly

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am using UIViewContainment in my iOS app. In have a contentView in my containerView and I am trying to load other views in it. The child views load fine by they are not sized correctly as shown in the screenshot.

NavigationBar is part of the container.

[image]

Here is the code I am using to load the childViewController inside the container.

```
  // load the new controller
    self.contentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:menuItem.viewControllerStoryboardId];

    [self.containerView addSubview:self.contentViewController.view];
    [self.contentViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:self.contentViewController];

    self.title = menuItem.title;
```

The following seems to work:

```
 self.contentViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, self.containerView.bounds.size.width, self.containerView.bounds.size.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to resize your contentViewController view:

```
 self.contentViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
 self.contentViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks! I just did that and it did not change anything. My childViewControllers do not have a navigation bar.

Comment: I edited my question with the possible answer that works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Start by commenting out your code which makes use of the container view. Now it's just a `UIView` like any other. Give it a background color or image to make sure it positions and resizes as desired.

If it isn't (and I'm guessing it's not) I can't help you to much with this because I know nothing about how you are doing it. Struts and Springs, AutoLayout, etc. Try to fix it yourself and if you can't, come back with layout details.

Let's say it IS working as expected with shape and size. Add your contained `UIViewController` back in. It means the `UIView` for this contained view controller is not the correct size/position inside it's super view (`self.containerView`).

Same process again. In `viewDidAppear` put a break point or logging and checked it's frame. You want to wait til all the views have gone through layout and that will have happened by the time you reach `viewDidAppear`.

If the view isn't where you expect it, try to figure it out and if you can't then come back with more details about how your doing your layout.

Comment: Found the issue! For some insane reason I had my contentView going all the way to the top behind the navigation bar. I adjusted it correctly and now it works!